# Cómo puedo subir mis cambios a GitHub mediante una llave SSH

Tags: git, github

Tengo problemas al intentar subir los cambios de mi repositorio local al remoto a través de una llave `ssh`:

> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes, ¿ya seguiste todos los pasos en [Generating an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)? O, en su defecto, leíste la sección [SSH](https://help.github.com/categories/ssh/) de GitHub Help

Comment: Ya segui los pasos, e inicie el ssh-agent pero el problema es que no me deja copiar la ruta de mi llave al ssh-agent   -->## Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: Juan,  podrías agregar por favor como estas intentando subir tus cambios, recuerda que es importante agregues información para poder diagnosticar con mejor acierto los problemas.

Comment: He repetido muchas veces este mismo proceso , 1. Empieze creando la llave atravez de ssh-keygen, 2. despues de creado abro la llave que se ha esta en la carpeta .ssh/id_rsa.pub, 3. Luego la agrego a github y depues inicializo el ssh-agent  ,pero cuando quiero subir cambios no me permite atravez de git push origin master , me muestra este mensaje    --> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: En caso ssh no puede hacer una conección a SSH agent trabaja sin el, preguntando todo en la terminal. Considera usar ssh puro sin git completamente: espero que tengas problemas con la conección, por causa del cortafuegos o algo.

Comment: @JuanDavid con tan poca información es difícil saber lo que te puede ocurrir ¿pudrías añadir algún detalle mas? el comando que usas, sistema operativo, esplicar un pocoi mas lo que pretendes hacer, ....

Comment: Lo que pretendo hacer es poder vincular mi proyecto remoto(`github`) con mi proyecto local, sin que tenga que estar recordando la password y el user, he creado mi llave ssh.keygen ,  he copiado agregado esta llave en github y ademas la he agregado al `ssh-agent`-->`ssh-add`, con esto creeria que ya es todo  pero al querer vincular mi repositorio atravez de `git remote add origin` tengo este problema  ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.@rsciriano

Comment: Uso OS ->w7 x64 -->git version 2.7.0.windows.1

Comment: pregunta, tu proyecto es de java, maven o alguna tecnología en particular?

Answer (score 2):

No es la respuesta completa, sólo un ejemplo como explorar el problema, no puedo ponerlo en los comentarios:

apagamos uso de ssh-agent:

```
alex@rhyme git/alt/log4cplus $ unset SSH_AGENT_PID
alex@rhyme git/alt/log4cplus $ unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

ahora nos conectamos a github.com sin git completamente:

```
alex@rhyme git/alt/log4cplus $ ssh -v git@github.com
OpenSSH_6.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alex/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/alex/.ssh/config line 145: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/openssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/openssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.129] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha2-512 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha2-512 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alex/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 817
debug1: key_load_private_type: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Enter passphrase for key '/home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa':
```

Podemos ver que ssh se ha parado para preguntar la clave en la terminal, sin uso el agente.

Ahora añadimos la configuración especifica de github.com a `.ssh/config':

```
Host github.com
   LogLevel DEBUG1
```

Repetimos con git:

```
alex@rhyme git/alt/log4cplus $ git clone git@github.com:wilx/log4cplus /var/tmp/log4cplus
Cloning into '/var/tmp/log4cplus'...
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/alex/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes256-ctr hmac-sha2-512 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes256-ctr hmac-sha2-512 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/alex/.ssh/known_hosts:14
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering DSA public key: /home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 817
debug1: key_load_private_type: incorrect passphrase supplied to decrypt private key
Enter passphrase for key '/home/alex/.ssh/id_dsa': 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to github.com ([192.30.252.130]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = ru_RU.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'wilx/log4cplus'
remote: Counting objects: 25373, done.
remote: Total 25373 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 25373
Receiving objects: 100% (25373/25373), 23.27 MiB | 3.22 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (18643/18643), done.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 15760, received 24451448 bytes, in 37.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 423.6, received 657153.1
debug1: Exit status 0
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Te aconsejo que verifiques que ssh puedas conectarse sin git, comparando el éxito de mi ejemplo y lo en tu ordenador.

P.S. perdona por favor mi Español, no soy hispanohablante nativo. Y no usé Google Translate tampoco.

**Edit:** Uso la clave [DSA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSA) y tu clave es RSA. Algunos proyectos [tienen/tenian problemas (en Inglés)](https://github.com/gitbucket/gitbucket/issues/553) con RSA. Quizas el cambio del tipo prodría eliminar el problema. Use `ssh-keygen -t dsa` para crear la clave.

Comment: Oye donde debo hacer esto ya que no se donde se encuentra esta carpeta o como hago este paso,   -->  configuración especifica de github.com a `.ssh/config':    mepodrias ayudar gracias

Comment: Pues, `$HOME/.ssh/config` es la carpeta para ssh configuraciones para cado usuario. Cree la nueva si no la tienes. El formato es muy simple, la linea `Host <Hostname>` y después algunas lineas con las opciones; en tu caso es la unica linea `LogLevel DEBUG1`. ¿Has intentado cambiar el tipo de la clave? ¿Qué has visto en el éxito de `ssh -v git@github.com`? Creo que sería útil mostrárnoslo en tú pregunta.

Comment: ` user3159253` muchas gracias por su colaboracion, ya he podido agregar los cambios a mi proyecto remoto , el motivo era por que no tenia el archivo `.ssh/config` creado con la configuracion especifica

Comment: Ok, entonces para los todos que podrian tener el mismo problema sería mejor explicar que problema era y cómo lo has reparado, quizá en una respuesta separada. .

Answer (score -1):

Asegurate de tener en tu `.git/config` el url correcto, es importante para `SSH` que agregues tu usuario:

> url = git@github.com:**nombreusuario**/repo.git

después vuelve a realizar:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Comment: Oye Elenasys cuando te refieres  `.git/config` esto desde donde lo debo hacer localmente o al copiar el repositorio de github en la clipboard